# How to set IIS Remote Management Restrictions policy using PowerShell (server core)?

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm setting up an IIS 2012 R2 system in a server core environment. I've enabled the IIS management service and assigned a cert, but can't find how to configure restrictions on what IPs can connect to 8172. The key:
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server\RemoteRestrictions
does it but is encoded so you can't just look at it and know what to put there. Kludged it by setting up on a system with a GUI and copying the key value but is there a right way? Knowing the string encoding would help if a registry edit is the only powershell option.

Answer (score 2):

This was the last part of our deploy process that was a manual step and I decided to take a shot at deciphering the RemoteRestrictions setting and have managed to come up with a solution to generate this setting.

You can find the full PowerShell script at the below gist which lets you define the global allow/deny setting and a set of IPs and Subnets to allow/deny

https://gist.github.com/guavadevelopment/7217d87943eb69ac60f0f96f3be00874

```
$remoteRestrictions = (Generate-RemoteRestrictions -globalDeny $True -addresses "1.1.1.1/255.255.255.255")
```

Few tips on the structure:

- The setting is Base64 encoded so you need to decode to get a byte array, the data is encoded directly into this byte array
- The first 21 bytes is a header

  - byte 12 encodes the global allow/deny 103=Allow, 104=Deny
  - bytes 18 to 21 are a 4 byte int which says how many ip address settings are to follow the header
- Following the header are 42 byte chunks for each ip address configured (you can define ipv6 ips and these create larger sections which I dont support)

  - bytes 1 to 4 are a zero based 4 byte int for the index of the ip address, this should increment by 1 for each ip added
  - bytes 17,19,21 and 23 represent each octet of the IP address
  - bytes 31,33,35 and 37 represent each octet of the Subnet address
  - byte 42 encodes the ip allow/deny 103=Allow, 104=Deny

Answer (score 1):

Great question... I don't think there is a good way. I don't see any documented way of setting it programmatically. The encoding looks like base64, so if you really desperately needed to automate this, try setting the RemoteRestrictions value through the GUI, and then try to replicate the same base64 string yourself using Powershell with something like this:

```
$RemoteRestrictions = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("192.168.1.50"))
```

If you can come up with the same string, then you've figured out their secret sauce. (Warning: this might be a fool's errand and a waste of your time. I've no idea what else they might put in there before base64 encoding it.)

But officially, I think your only recourse is to remotely manage this IIS server from another server that has the RSAT (remote server administration tools) installed.

Edit: Actually I think REG_SZ values are UTF-16 little endian (each character is two bytes long,) so you may need to use the UTF16 class instead of UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that the encoding is the same on any machine, so copying the string from another machine should work fine.

The string in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server\RemoteRestrictions` is base64 encoded and

```
[System.Convert]::FromBase64String($input)
```

returns a byte array, but I was unable to turn that into a string that makes sense.

Comment: Loading the URL into some Edge somewhere and retrieving the hash is what I am going to do if I can't get the logic to create the hash myself. I'm wanting to turn this over to someone who is not going to know how to extract an existing hash. I just want them to supply a url and a description and my code poke the favorite in from the command line.

Comment: Ignore: responding to wrong question.